# Regex Replace on a JSON structure

Tags: c#, regex, json

I am currently trying to do a Regex Replace on a JSON string that looks like:

```
String input = "{\"`####`Answer_Options11\": \"monkey22\",\"`####`Answer_Options\": \"monkey\",\"Answer_Options2\": \"not a monkey\"}";
```

a
The goal is to find and replace all the value fields who's key field starts with `####`

I currently have this:

```
static Regex _FieldRegex = new Regex(@"`####`\w+" + ".:.\"(.*)\",");

static public string MatchKey(string input)
{
    MatchCollection match = _encryptedFieldRegex.Matches(input.ToLower());
    string match2 = "";
    foreach (Match k in match )
    {
        foreach (Capture cap in k.Captures)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("" + cap.Value);
            match2 = Regex.Replace(input.ToLower(), cap.Value.ToString(), @"CAKE");
        }
    }

    return match2.ToString();
}
```

Now this isn't working. Naturally I guess since it picks up the entire `####`Answer_Options11\": \"monkey22\",\"`####`Answer_Options\": \"monkey\", as a match and replaces it. I want to just replace the `match.Group[1]` like you would for a single match on the string.

At the end of the day the JSON string needs to look something like this:

```
String input = "{\"`####`Answer_Options11\": \"CATS AND CAKE\",\"`####`Answer_Options\": \"CAKE WAS A LIE\",\"Answer_Options2\": \"not a monkey\"}";
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Deserialize the JSON, do your manipulations and then serialize it again. Trying to do this on the serialized form will blow up horribly in some edge case you just haven't though of yet.

Comment: Wouldn't this be far easier and cleaner if you parsed the JSON as the datastructure that it is and then just replaced inside the values?

Comment: Hi guys, sorry should have added this in the question. Can't serialize it to a object ( we have many different objects and don't know what they are ). The plan for this is to be used as a general change these marked fields to something.

Comment: You can use something like `JObject` from JSON.NET to deserialize an object even if you don't know the structure beforehand. I'm sure other options exist.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to know it translates to something like `Person.Name = Guy`? Which would be a problem. Since any given thing we pass in can have many different fields/names etc.

Comment: `Dictionary` is a great data structure :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working from [@Jonesy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1786428/jonesy)'s answer I got to this which works for what I wanted. It includes the .Replace on the groups that I required. The negative look ahead and behinds were very interesting but I needed to replace some of those values hence groups.

```
    static public string MatchKey(string input)
    {

       string strRegex = @"(__u__)(.+?:\s*)""(.*)""(,|})*";
        Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
        IQS_Encryption.Encryption enc = new Encryption();

        int count = 1;

        string addedJson = "";

        int matchCount = 0;
        foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(input))
        {

            if (myMatch.Success)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("REGEX MYMATCH: " + myMatch.Value);
                input = input.Replace(myMatch.Value, "__e__" + myMatch.Groups[2].Value + "\"c" +  count + "\"" + myMatch.Groups[4].Value);
                addedJson += "c"+count + "{" +enc.EncryptString(myMatch.Groups[3].Value, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("12345678912365478912365478965412"))+"},";
            }

            count++;
            matchCount++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("MAC" + matchCount);
        return input + addedJson;
    }`
```

Thanks again to [@Jonesy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1786428/jonesy) for the huge help.

Answer (score 2):

you want a positive lookahead and a positive lookbehind :

`(?<=####.+?:).*?(?=,)`

the lookaheads and lookbehinds will verify that it matches those patterns, but not include them in the match. [This site](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) explains the concept pretty well.

Generated code from RegexHero.com :

```
string strRegex = @"(?<=####.+?:).*?(?=,)";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex);
string strTargetString = @" ""{\""`####`Answer_Options11\"": \""monkey22\"",\""`####`Answer_Options\"": \""monkey\"",\""Answer_Options2\"": \""not a monkey\""}""";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
     // Add your code here
  }
}
```

this will match `"monkey22"` and `"monkey"` but not `"not a monkey"`

Comment: Hi, I checked this out in RegexHero.com, if I add another `####` something something at the end it doesn't pick that up. Instead it picks up the previous `not a monkey` because it gets a `,` added after it. I need it to get the `monkey` field for every field starting with `####`